# How do I modify a class method?

Tags: javascript

I have code that looks like this (simplified)

```js
class foo {
  constructor() {
    this.bar()
  }

  bar() {
    // other code ...
    console.log('original');
  }
}

new foo(); // output: "original"
```

I would look to add more code inside the `bar()` method without affecting what already exists.

So something like this

```
bar() {
  // original code fires
  // then...
  console.log('new stuff');
}
```

and the final output would look like

```
original
new stuff
```

A couple of notes:

1. I don't want to override `bar()` - I just want to add to it.
2. I don't to call `bar()` - it's called upstream and I just want to piggyback on that call.
3. I've been reading about [super](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super) but that seems to be more related to sub-classes (which I don't want to create)

So I guess here's my question:

Is it possible to add to the contents of a class method in the way I described above?

Comment: Why don't you want to create a child class? This is exactly what they are for.

Comment: You want to change the behavior of a method without 1) changing the method and 2) overriding the method?

Comment: What you explain is not possible. Yous should either extend the main class or modify the source code of the class.

Comment: @matthew-e-brown I definitely agree that creating a subclass would be a lot easier, but that's not an option because the the `bar()` method in the parent class is quite big and would be difficult to maintain.

Comment: Correct, @RobbyCornelissen, and I'm guessing the answer is that it's not possible?

Comment: @volt, does `bar()` actually need to be called in the constructor? as you mentioned "it is called upstream "

Comment: Thanks @MerianosNikos I had a feeling it might not be possible, but figured I should ask just in case. I explained why I can't extend the main class above, and editing the source is also not an option I'm afraid.

Comment: @volt That's the point of using `super()`. You don't need to do any "maintaining," you just run the original code and then maintain your own. I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "difficult to maintain."

Comment: I might using the wrong terms @Jacob but yes, `bar()` is called in the constructor.

Comment: Then I think I don't understand `super()` well enough @matthew-e-brown

Comment: @volt If you create a new class that extends `foo` and declare a method inside of it where you call "`super.bar()`" (I think that's the syntax, it's been a while since I used classes in JS), it will run the original `foo` implementation of `bar`. This means that you can declare a function that runs the original `bar` at any point. You could even write it so that it runs `bar` twelve times. The new implementation doesn't even need to be called `bar`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is almost certainly an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but the literal solution of your question:

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.bar()
  }

  bar() {
    // other code ...
    console.log('original');
  }
}

new Foo(); // output: "original"

const addedLine = 'console.log("new stuff");\n';
const source = Foo.prototype.bar.toString();
let [_, args, body] = source.match(/^.*?\((.*?)\)\s*{([^]*)}\s*$/);
body += addedLine;
args = args.split(/\s*,\s*/);
Foo.prototype.bar = Function(...args, body);

new Foo(); // output: "original", "new stuff"
```

**Warning:** *This is extremely hacky!* Outside of proof of concept, you should not consider doing this in production code.

A bit less hacky solution, that mimics `super` (and is more restricted than the black magic above):

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.bar()
  }

  bar() {
    // other code ...
    console.log('original');
  }
}

new Foo(); // output: "original"

(() => {
  const oldBar = Foo.prototype.bar;
  Foo.prototype.bar = function() {
    oldBar.apply(this, arguments);
    console.log("new stuff");
  }
})();

new Foo(); // output: "original", "new stuff"
```

EDIT: It bugs me when classes start with a lowercase.

Comment: in line 17 of your last example it reads ... `oldBar();` ... thus it misses both applying context and passing the arguments ... the corrected line should really look like 
 that ... `oldBar.apply(this, arguments);`

Comment: @PeterSeliger You are right; the example method did not use `this` nor had any arguments, and I overlooked that concern.

Comment: You answered my question almost a year ago, and that's how long it took for me to learn enough about js classes to really appreciate your answer. Storing `oldBar` and then adding `oldBar.apply(this, arguments)` is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you add a new method inside the class and that method can use other methods in that class eg

```
foo.prototype.modifiedBoo = () => {
    console.log("I'm modified!")
  }; 

  console.log(new foo.modifiedBoo())

  // I'm modified!
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use inheritance, maybe you can use composition:

```js
class foo {
  constructor() {
    this.bar()
  }

  bar() {
    // other code ...
    console.log('original');
  }
}

new foo(); // output: "original"

class FooWrapper {
  f;
  
  constructor() {
    this.bar();
  }

  bar() {
    console.log("other code...");
    this.f = new foo();
  }

}

new FooWrapper();


class WhateverWrapper {
  whatever;
  
  constructor(wrapped) {
    this.bar();
    this.whatever = new wrapped();
  }

  bar() {
    console.log("other code...");
  }

}

new WhateverWrapper(foo);
```